# Get pointcollection from a path in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a path object drawn using `PolyBezierSegment`. It is added on a `Canvas`. I have to fetch the object from the `Canvas.Children` list in a different code block and then need to retrieve the `PointCollection` of the fetched Path.

How can I get the PointCollection?

Comment: There is no `PointCollection` in a `Path`. Did you mean the [`Path.Data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns a `Geometry` object?

Comment: @Sheridan  Yes that is what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research and thinking I found the answer.

```
public static PointCollection getPointsFromPath(Path path)
    {


        PointCollection pathPointsCollection = new PointCollection();

        PathFigure pathFigure = null;
        PolyBezierSegment polyBezierSegment = null;
        PathGeometry pathGeometry = (PathGeometry)path.Data;
        PathFigureCollection pathFigureCollection = pathGeometry.Figures;
        if (pathFigureCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                pathFigure = pathFigureCollection.ElementAt(0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception found at getting path figure=" + e);
            }

            if (pathFigure != null)
            {
                PathSegmentCollection pathSegmentCollection = pathFigure.Segments;

                try
                {
                    polyBezierSegment = (PolyBezierSegment)pathSegmentCollection[0];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception found at getting polyBezierSegment =" + e);
                }
                if (polyBezierSegment != null)
                {
                    pathPointsCollection = polyBezierSegment.Points;
                }


            }

        }

        //Console.WriteLine("pathPointsCollection.Count=" + pathPointsCollection.Count + " values=" + pathPointsCollection.ToString());

        return pathPointsCollection;
    }
```

Comment: But be aware that the Points of a PolyBezierSegment do not represent a polygonal approximation of the curve. You would have to use something like the [Geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615674.aspx) method.